# SQL statement help!

Tags: sql

I need help in sql statement. Now my database I have Category table(book, flower, stationary). Inside book table(bookIDm,bookTypes, size, price, catID)

> For eg, 1st field -1(bookID), Diary(bookTypes), Big(size), $12.50(price), 1(catID)
>   2nd field -2(bookID), Diary(bookTypes), Big(size), $11.00(price), 1(catID) .

Now I just wanted it to display like ---- Diary | Small | $11.00---Means only display one data for each bookType with the lowest price. How do I write the sql statement for this requirement?

Comment: Please write a question that isn't a massive blob of unformatted text.

Comment: It's still a massive blob of text.

Answer (score 3):

For Microsoft SQL Server you could use

```
SELECT     BookType, Size, MIN(Price) AS LowestPrice
FROM         dbo.Books
GROUP BY BookType, Size
```

The main things you are looking to learn are the use of agregate functions. I suggest you check out [Aggregate Functions (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173454.aspx) .I used the Min function here to get the minimum price. To do this you must use the "[Group By](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx)" for the fields that are not agregated.

Answer (score 1):

```
select BookType, Size, min(Price)
from Book
group by BookType, Size
order by BookType
```